# Is there a way to pass a member function into a method by reference? [JAVA]

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement a counter in my app that increases every time the button is clicked. I then want to take the whatever the final value of the counter is and have it displayed in a dialog.

The problem is that when I call the variable, it returns the value that it initially had, not the one modified by the onClick method (This is weird to explain but I commented in my code to show what I mean).

```
    final TextView points = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.points);
    points.setText("Points = 0");

    class ButtonClick implements View.OnClickListener {
        int value = 0;
        public void onClick(View v) {
            value++;
            changeLocation(theButton);
            points.setText("Points = " + value); // This value increases
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        } // This returns 0.
    }

    final ButtonClick buttonClicked = new ButtonClick();
    theButton.setOnClickListener(buttonClicked);

    final int finalValue = buttonClicked.getValue(); // This still equals zero.
```

Comment: Java doesn't have pointers.

Comment: Re, "// This still equals zero."  _When_ does it still equal zero?  Does your program literally execute those last three lines in some method?  I.e., does it create the new ButtonClick object, register it, and then immediately get its value?  In that case, of course its value still is zero!  You haven't given the user any time in which to click the button.

Comment: @jameslarge I'm so silly; your comment is what got me to the correct answer! I called the getValue function way too early.  (still new to Java/first app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is executed synchronously line by line:

```
      // define and instantiate button listener 
1)    final ButtonClick buttonClicked = new ButtonClick();
      // attach listener to button
2)    theButton.setOnClickListener(buttonClicked);

            <------ here you still didn't executed onClick :) 

      // trying get value 
3)    final int finalValue = buttonClicked.getValue(); // This still equals zero.
```

When you hit line 3, you are getting value 0 because value is zero.

Try clicking (perform click -> do event or whatsoever ) then get value.

To see if it works, you need a second asynchronous method example:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            while(buttonClicked.getValue() ==0) {
                   // you didn't click

                     Thread.sleep(10000);
            }
       };
}).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues that I can see,
1) onClick is not the overridden method, so try @Override annotation like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) { ... }
```

2) When a variable has to be used across, try to declare it in class level with getters and setters also at class level.

Hope these tips will help.